# Is `this.foo` always the same as `foo.bind(this)`?

Tags: javascript, this, bind

Just wondering if these two are always the same, and if not in what context? I think I understand 'bind' and 'this', I just want to be sure.

The context of what I'm trying to understand, above and beyond 'bind' and 'this',

I have an object..

```
var Foo = Class.create({
  a: func.bind(this),
  b: func
});
```

Are and `a` and `b`'s `this` the same? What's the difference in the two. If `b` gets the this, of the callee that callee in the context of `Foo.b` is `Foo`. In the case of `a` we're explicitly saying `this` is the object at the time we install the method `a`.

Comment: `this.foo()` is the same as `this.foo.bind(this)()`. Your statement is not always true. For example when you're in a function scope and `this` equals to `undefined`

Comment: That's not /exactly/ what I asked. ;)

Comment: Okay, let's play pedants! :-)

Comment: Well, no, I'm not trying too. But, this is Javascript. Context can change with callbacks, and such.

Comment: I would even say that it's almost never the same. Heck, that's the reason for the entire *existence* of the `.bind` method!

Comment: Now it's a different question! :-) "the same" --- what does it *exactly* mean? If you compare them with `==` you will notice they are not the same. As they are references to 2 different objects.

Comment: If the real question is are the side effects produced by `Foo.a` and `Foo.b` are the same - then the answer is: it depends on how you invoke it.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to understand, when are the different when are the side effects the same? I'm confused about this specific context of 'this'.

Comment: `this` is resolved in runtime on call. Without code that invokes those functions it's not possible to say if they behave the same or not.

Comment: Class.create is not javascript, so something weird could be under the hood there, but if not, in the case of `foo.a(),foo.b()`, the _this_ is the same, both are _foo_. in the case of `setTimeout(foo.a,1),setTimeout(foo.b,1)` they are different: a's _this_ would be _foo_ and b's would be _window_ in full mode or _undefined_ in a 'use strict' subset.

Comment: also other execution contexts will over-ride methodical _this_, `[1,2,3].map(Foo.b, {a:1})` for example

Answer (score 1):

It's not always the same.

Example:

```
'use strict';

function bar() {
    // here is your code
}

bar();
```

Here is when `this.foo` and `foo.bind(this)` are different, because `this` is `undefined` in the `bar` when `'use strict';` is used.

**UPDATE** for the updated question:

> Are and a and b's this the same? What's the difference in the two. If b gets the this, of the callee that callee in the context of Foo.b is Foo. In the case of a we're explicitly saying this is the object at the time we install the method a.

They are references to 2 different objects. And the behaviour of invocation depends on how exactly you call them. Without the code that calls them it's not possible to say if they behave in similar or in different way.

```
var Foo = Object.create({
  a: func.bind(this),
  b: func
});

Foo.a();
Foo.b();
```

With this code they will behave differently:

1. `this` inside the `func` in case `a` will be equal to `this` from the scope of `func.bind(this)` call
2. `this` inside the `func` in case `b` will be equal to `Foo`

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tsuddg1o/

**Another update**

Your object construction code is equal to:

```
var tmp = func.bind(this);

var Foo = Object.create({
  a: tmp,
  b: func
});
```

Comment: why? could you explain?

Comment: @EvanCarroll added explanation. But that's not what you wanted to know (but you wanted to get the exact answer!) :-D

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. If no one else has any other exaples of where they're different, I'll accept this. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @EvanCarroll I think it's useless :-)

Comment: So when I do, `var obj = new Foo` how does that play with the scope of `this` in that context -- would they both be the same?

Comment: @EvanCarroll nope, `func.bind(this)` is executed **before** the object is constructed so `this` is what `this` refers to in the current scope. See another update.